# Calculating A Sample Test Score in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am asked the following questions and came up with a solution but I can't seem to figure out how the other conditions are met or satisfied.

```
function scoreTest(correct, questions) {
var percent;
// Only change code below this line
percent = (correct*questions); // My logic


// Only change code above this line
return percent;
}

// Change the inputs below to test your code
scoreTest(18,20);

scoreTest(20,25) should return a number //Output met
scoreTest(47,50) should return a value of 94
scoreTest(16,20) should return a value of 80
scoreTest(8,10) should return a value of 80 //Output met
scoreTest(97,100) should return a value of 97
scoreTest(1,50) should return a value of 2
```

Comment: "the following questions" you forgot to include the referenced questions.

Comment: It's not clear what you want the function to do by the examoples

Comment: it should be ```(correct/questions) * 100```

Comment: You had no math in school? This is basic arithmetics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It is about basic arithmetics and requires primary school level math knowledge.

Comment: @connexo How do you know OP was fortunate enough to go to primary school?

Answer (score 3):

You are so close.  Percentages are calculated like this `(numberCorrect / TotalQuestions) * 100`.  This will give you a percentage value.

Given this, re-factor your function to output a percentage:

```js
function scoreTest(correct, questions) {
var percent;
// Only change code below this line
percent = (correct/questions) * 100; // Actual percentage value


// Only change code above this line
return percent;
}

// Change the inputs below to test your code
scoreTest(18,20);

scoreTest(20,25) //should return a number //Output met
scoreTest(47,50) //should return a value of 94
scoreTest(16,20) //should return a value of 80
scoreTest(8,10) //should return a value of 80 //Output met
scoreTest(97,100) //should return a value of 97
scoreTest(1,50) //should return a value of 2
```

Comment: ahh!  I hate being that close and not getting it man.  It's gonna bug me all night.  Thanks for the logic Marcus.  Happy coding.

Comment: My pleasure! Sometimes, we forget about the simplest things haha. Good luck!